# tf.reshape with the tensor size raises mismatched number of values

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following code:

```py
    shape = tf.shape(tensor, out_type=tf.int64, name='sparse_shape')
    nelems = tf.size(tensor, out_type=tf.int64, name='num_elements')
    indices = tf.transpose(
        tf.unravel_index(tf.range(nelems, dtype=tf.int64), shape),
        name='sparse_indices')
    values = tf.reshape(tensor, [nelems], name='sparse_values')
```

This code snippet is simply transforming a dense tensor into a sparse tensor. However I found that the `reshape` op sometimes raises an error in runtime:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 906 values, but the requested shape has 1024
```

It's hard to write a simple demo to reproduce this bad case. So please understand that I cannot provide a reproducible demo.

But notice that my code is very simple. The `reshape` op is simply reshaping the tensor into a 1D tensor with the dimension size as the tensor's `size`, which is **the number of elements** of the tensor (illustrated in TensorFlow's doc). And in my mind, **the number of elements** here simply means **the number of of values** in the error message. Thus the above error should never appear.

I tried to use production of the shape as the target dimension size instead of `tf.size` but it was no use:

```py
    shape = tf.shape(tensor, out_type=tf.int64, name='sparse_shape')
    # use production as the number of elements
    nelems = tf.reduce_prod(shape, name='num_elements')
    ....
    values = tf.reshape(tensor, [nelems], name='sparse_values')
```

So my question is, why is there a possibility that, for a certain tensor `tensor`, `tf.size(tensor)` or `tf.shape(tensor)` does not tell the actual **number of elements** of `tensor`? Can anyone remind if I have missed anything? Thanks.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what reshape does, not all reshape inputs are possible, the number of elements in the array should not change, and you cannot do a reshape to 1024 elements if 906 (less than 1024) elements are available.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks for the comment. I think you are misunderstanding my question. In my case, `tf.size` tells that a tensor has 1024 elements. But `tf.reshape` tells that the same tensor has 906 elements. So **my question is** "why does these two ops give different number of elements on the same tensor", **BUT NOT** "why cannot I reshape a tensor with 906 elements to 1024 elements".

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem on myself.

### Problem:

In my project, the problem is that, `tensor` is produced by a third-party library. The library called `tensor.set_shape([1024])` before returning `tensor`. While it can't ensure that there must be 1024 elements in `tensor`.

According to [these codes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py#L656), in TensorFlow's python frontend implementation, when the shape is fully determined, `tf.shape` and `tf.size` can go a fast way to get the result without really running the `ShapeOp` or `SizeOp`, and returning a constant tensor of the determined shape dimensions as the result.

As a result, in my case, the shape is obviously fully determined as `[1024]`, so the code goes in the fast way and returned `tf.constant([1024])`. However the real shape of the `Tensor` object in the backend is `[906]`.

### Solution

According to the previously mentioned codes, we can see that `tf.shape` and `tf.size` actually calls `shape_internal` and `size_internal` defined in `tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops`. The latter functions takes one more argument `optimize` with default value `True`. And if `optimize` is false, the fast way will be ignored.

So the solution is to replace the `tf.shape` or `tf.size` with `shape_internal` or `size_internal`, and pass `optimize=False`.

```py
# internal functions are not exposed by `tensorflow` root package
# so we have to import the `array_ops` package manualy
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops

....

shape = tf.shape(tensor, out_type=tf.int64, name='sparse_shape')

#nelems = tf.size(tensor, out_type=tf.int64, name='num_elements')
nelems = array_ops.size_internal(tensor, optimize=False, out_type=tf.int64, name='num_elements')

....

values = tf.reshape(tensor, [nelems], name='sparse_values')
```